# onActivityResult Intent is null when passing Intent from Adapter

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I am facing a strange issue while returning to an Activity with a Result, I am passing an Intent for `startActivityForResult` from an Adapter like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(activity, EditInfoActivity.class);
i.putExtra("id", list.get(position).getID());
activity.startActivityForResult(i, 100);
```

and in second Activity i.e. in EditInfoActivity in my case on a `Button` click I am setting Result for first activity like this:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
i.putExtra("isDataChange", isDataChange);
setResult(100, i);
finish();
```

In Activity's `onActivityResult` method I am able to get result code but getting `Intent` `null`.

Why? anybody have any idea on this please share.

in Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == 100) {
    //Here data is null and app crash
    if (data.getExtras() != null && data.getBooleanExtra("isDataChange", false)) {
       recreate();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you need to start the Activity with a **REQUEST_CODE**:

```
// Here we set a constant for the code.
private final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;

Intent i = new Intent(activity, EditInfoActivity.class);
i.putExtra("id", list.get(position).getID());
activity.startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Then you need to send **RESULT_OK** when finishing EditInfoActivity:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
i.putExtra("isDataChange", isDataChange);
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

Then handle the result on your first activity with this:

```
Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // REQUEST_CODE is defined as 100
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100) {
     // do process
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`setResult` TAKES `RESULT_CODE` instead of REQUEST_CODE.

Replace your code with this, May be it will solve your problem.

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
```

And in yout `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
   //Here data is null and app crash
        if (data != null && data.getBooleanExtra("isDataChange", false)) {
            recreate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two mistakes. You are passing the intent that was used to launch the activity you are finishing. Use `new Intent()` instead.

When setting activity result you should use result codes, not a request code `setResult(RESULT_OK)` alternatively `RESULT_CANCELED` and handle the response accordingly.